# Word for Hanging Water

Tags: terminology

Is there a word to describe a gathering lump of water hanging on a surface that has not yet produced a droplet? Imagine a small pool of water without the surface upon which it's resting.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with camelbrush's answer, but I also thought of the less technical word of ***bead***.

As a noun, [*bead* means:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bead)

> any small globular or cylindrical body, as a drop of liquid or a bubble in an effervescent liquid: *beads of sweat*.

As a verb, *bead* means:

> to bead, to form into beads or drops

I think of a bead as a droplet forming, but before it drops as a droplet.

Answer (score 6):

The word you are looking for is [pendant as in this wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension), and I remember it from physics lectures about [surface tension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_tension). But technically, a [pendant is also a drop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop_%28liquid%29), and a drop is defined as :

> A drop or droplet is a small column of liquid, bounded completely or almost completely by free surfaces. A drop may form when liquid accumulates at the lower end of a tube or other surface boundary, producing a hanging drop called a pendant drop.

Also, there is an adjective: [Pendent](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pendent?q=pendent), which is used for anything hanging down.